# how to deal with models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have a problem how to create an login and register for a model that i create but nothing work good

i try this for login

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.success(request, "You are Already logged in ")
        redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            form = login_client(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                client = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
                if client is not None:
                    login(request, client)
                    return redirect("/")
                
        else :
            form = login_client()
        return render(request, 'Login.html', {"form":form})
```

and for the register page i try this

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.success(request, "You are Already logged in")
        return redirect("/")
    else :
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = addNewClient(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                return redirect('login')
        else :
            form = addNewClient()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {"form":form})
```

and this is the model in the file models.py

```
class Clients(models.Model) :
    created_at     = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    idClient       = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name     = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name      = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email          = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    username       = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    password       = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and for the forms.py this the code bellow
the class addNewclient for register
and the class login_client is for login the user

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from .models import Clients


class addNewClient(forms.ModelForm):
    email       = forms.EmailField(label="Email", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Ex : JhonWick@gmail.com"}))
    first_name  = forms.CharField(label="First Name ", widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Ex : Jhon"}))
    last_name   = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Ex : Wick"}))
    username    = forms.CharField(label='Username',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Ex : JhonWick"}))
    password    = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Ex : 32FFdl@d"}))
    
    class Meta :
        model = Clients
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']


class login_client(forms.Form,):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

Comment: Add your **forms.py** and how is `Client` model related to the **User** model?

Comment: i edited the code in the top can you help me with this bug